# How do I change resolution without screen in Jupiter applet?

Tags: resolution, screen, jupiter

I have a problem. Screen broke on my netbook, so I decided to connect it to TV. The first thing I did was changing screen resolution with Jupiter Applet to too large, so TV switch off and didn't show anything from netbook.

Please, help me! I don't know how I can set screen resolution to standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change to a tty (ctrl alt F1) then login and use
xrandr -q 'this will display a list of modes with the connected device for you to choose'

set the one you want with

```
xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1920x1080
```

For example, make sure you use the correct display identifier given by `xrandr -q`, mine being LVDS.

You can see which from the output of xrandr -q
for example mine is

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1920
LVDS connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then when set, switch back to your desktop with ctrl alt F7 (possibly F8 if F7 doesnt do it)